# Auto populate column with value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Using SQL Management Studio, I have two tables, the first table contains information about each operator. The second table containing data input.

The first table will contain a `UserID`, e.g. "Ollie" with their corresponding hours, e.g. 8.
When data is input to the second table, with an Operator name of "Ollie", I need a field within this second table to auto fill as "8".

The following is the table data from the second table, and a rough showing of what I am after.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTime](
    [RecordID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Operator] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Timein] [decimal](10, 4) NOT NULL,
    [UserBreak] [decimal](10, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Timeout] [decimal](10, 4) NOT NULL,
    [TotalTime]  AS (([Timeout]-[Timein])-[Userbreak]),
    [OperatorHours] AS (SELECT OperatorHours FROM tblUser t WHERE t.UserID = Operator),
```

Comment: You can do this by defining a function that returns the value.  However, you cannot include a subquery as a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use subqueries for computed columns. You can write trigger for this purpose.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerExample
ON TblTime
BEFORE INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
 Declare @operH int;
 SELECT @operH = OperatorHours FROM tblUser t WHERE t.UserID = inserted.operator;
 inserted.OperatorHours = @operH;
GO
```

Comment: I have been able to modify this and almost get it working, ssms doesn't seem to like "BEFORE"

Comment: check my edited answer please. try with `BEFORE INSERT, UPDATE`

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately ssms does not like the before statement. It wants after, or for